# Sending data after password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form to insert user to a database. On the other side I have two scripts of password validation and ajax script which retrieve php result.

Right now the two script are working separately.

What should I do so that the ajax script run after the password validation?

**Password Validation**

```
 function Validate() {
        var password = document.getElementById("UserPwd").value;
        var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("ConfirmUserPwd").value;
        if (password != confirmPassword) {
            alert("Please enter the same password");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Script**

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "insert_sp.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {submit: 'true'},
      success: function(response) {

        var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

**Update**

isset : `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))`

button : `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>`

```
$(function() {
  $("#myForm").on("sumbit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var password = $("#UserPwd").val(),
      confirmPassword = $("#ConfirmPassword").val(); 
    if ($.trim(password) === password && 
        password !== "" &&               
        password === confirmPassword) { 
      $.ajax({
        url: "insert_sp.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          submit: 'true' 
        },
        success: function(response) {
          var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      alert("Please enter the same password");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970071/how-to-perform-some-action-before-submit-form-via-ajaxform this might help

Comment: Now the question does no longer make sense - but you still need to change `submit: 'true' ` to `Submit: 'true' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Never call anything "submit" in a form. It will hide the submit event if you need it.
2. Use the form's submit event and event.preventDefault instead of submit buttons click events
3. If you have jQuery, why not use it all the way?
4. Remember to do the exact same validation on the server before inserting

I cannot make you a running snippet because SO does not allow submit in their pages. Here is the code - it should work as designed

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel form submission
    var password = $("#UserPwd").val(),
      confirmPassword = $("#ConfirmPassword").val();
    console.log(password,confirmPassword)  
    if ($.trim(password) === password && // spaces?
      password !== "" && // empty?
      password === confirmPassword) { // the same?
      $.ajax({
        url: "insert_sp.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          Submit: 'true' // remember to change the $_POST test too
        },
        success: function(response) {
          var data = $.parseJSON(response);
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("Please enter the same password");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="password" value="" id="UserPwd" /><br/>
  <input type="password" value="" id="ConfirmPassword" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is your point of _Never call anything "submit" in a form_ refer to the submits of the button? I'm a beginner and trying to understand. Is there any different if I tell you I use `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` for the submit?

Comment: The point is that form.submit will no longer be an event but the button. Just change the $_POST['submit'] to $_POST['Submit'] or something else and change the name of the button to Submit if you need.

Comment: Alright, I get it. I've tried your solution but when I entered differents password, the data is still sent to the db. @mplungjan

Comment: Look in console

Comment: There is no error. @mplungjan . I updated my question. If you don't mind can you please have a look?

Comment: You should not have updated the question since now it no longer makes sense. You do have to change the  `submit: 'true'` to `Submit: 'true'` since you changed the $_POST test on the server

Comment: The password validation worked perfectly. But unexpectedly this error come out `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` at this line `var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);` . I think I have to ask a new question. Thank you for your time :) I learned a lot.

Comment: Make sure your JSON is valid

Comment: `Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'` The error I got when validate the json @mplungjan . Now, a popup which contains html code of xdebug-error and some of my user form keep coming out for success response.

Comment: Please ask a new question. Be sure to include the JSON structure with an example

Comment: PS> No need to do native JSON parsing when using jQuery anyway: var `data = $.parseJSON(response);`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800415/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/42800919#42800919) .

Answer (score 0):

Make a other functuon of ajax request after password validation if success then call ajax function like below.

```
function ajax_request(){
$.ajax({
url: "insert_sp.php",
method: "POST",
data: {submit: 'true'},    
success: function(response) {
var data=JSON&&JSON.parse(response)||$.parseJSON(response);
alert(data);
console.log(data);
}
});

function Validate() {
var password = document.getElementById("UserPwd").value;
var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value;
if (password == confirmPassword) {
ajax_request();            
}else{
alert("Wrong Password");
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Hai @bharatsavani . Could you guide me on your point of _Make other function of ajax request after password validation_ ? I'm kind of lost.

Comment: you have required password is correct so if password is correct so call ajax function simple logic. @Mint

Comment: I get it now, I try your solution but they don't work. The form can't be submitted and there is no password validation. Any idea? @bharatsavani

Comment: which type of password validation you required

Comment: I just need the password validation to make sure user enter their password and confirm them before sending their data @bharatsavani